# Creating a smart contract that only accepts a specific ERC20 token

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, payable, sendtransaction

Currently building a smart contract that will basically receive money from users and users can withdraw what they've put into.
I want the money held by the smart contract to be only USDC (+ USDT maybe, but let's first focus on one token).

How can I do that please ?

PS : as you guessed, I don't own the token (similar questions have been asked but they all assumed you have created the ERC20 token).

Comment: In the deposit function you can have an if condition with the address of USDT ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way that you can stop someone from sending arbitrary coins to your contract's address. "Sending" coins is essentially the same as writing someone's address in a database next to a number. You can't stop someone from simply writing values on chain if you don't own the logic behind how that data is written.

If you take a look at the [ERC20 token](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/af7ec04b78c2b5dec330153de90682b13f17a1bb/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L226) that OpenZeppelin provides, you will find that the only addresses that are blacklisted are the zero address, on lines 231 & 232. Otherwise, there is nothing that stops the user from transferring from one arbitrary address to another.
As Majd TL suggested in the comments, you can have a deposit function that serves as the "correct" method of depositing coin via approval + deposit.